# Job via Oozie HDP 2.1 not creating job.splitmetainfo

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

When trying to execute a sqoop job which has my Hadoop program passed as a jar file in `-jarFiles` parameter, the execution blows off with below error. Any resolution seems to be not available. Other jobs with same Hadoop user is getting executed successfully.

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.staging/job_1423050964699_0003/job.splitmetainfo
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.createSplits(JobImpl.java:1541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:976)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$JobEventDispatcher.handle(MRAppMaster.java:1241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceStart(MRAppMaster.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.run(MRAppMaster.java:1452)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1381)
```

Comment: Have the same problem running camusjob. Did you solve it? I'm running on CDH5

Comment: @Sergey --> Pass all the options in workflow.xml under args property. E.g. <args>import</args>
       <args>-libjars</args>
       <args>jar-file-name</args>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the way I solved it. We are using CDH5 to run Camus to pull data from kafka. We run CamusJob which is responsible for getting data from kafka using comman line:

```
hadoop jar...
```

The problem is that new hosts didn't get so-called "yarn-gateway". Cloudera names pack of configs related to service and copied to `/etc/hadoop/conf`
as "gateway". So I just clicked "`deploy client configuration`" in CM UI. YARN client conf has been copied to each YARN NodeManager node and it solved problem.