# Executing oozie job - yarn problems

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I am trying to execute bash script, which contains multiple hive commands using oozie. I have encountered several exceptions:

1. **permission-issue** - [impersonate oozie job - permission issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716336/impersonate-oozie-job-permission-issue) - solved by disabling the security or changing the permissions
2. **File not found exception** (org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://:8020/user/hdfs/.staging//job.splitmetainfo) the full stack-trace appears bellow.

**Couple of facts:**

1. We are using hortwonworks 2.0 stack 2.2.6
2. I am pretty sure that the problem is somewhere with the ozzie job/ configuration (The script works just fine from command line).

What am i missing here?

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://<my_hadoop_server>:8020/user/hdfs/.staging/<job_id>/job.splitmetainfo
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.createSplits(JobImpl.java:1568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$JobEventDispatcher.handle(MRAppMaster.java:1289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceStart(MRAppMaster.java:1057)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$4.run(MRAppMaster.java:1500)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1429)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://<my_hadoop_server>:8020/user/hdfs/.staging/<job_id>/job.splitmetainfo
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.split.SplitMetaInfoReader.readSplitMetaInfo(SplitMetaInfoReader.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.createSplits(JobImpl.java:1563)
    ... 17 more
```

Please advise.

*References:*

- [Job via Oozie HDP 2.1 not creating job.splitmetainfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337183/sqoop-job-via-oozie-hdp-2-1-not-creating-job-splitmetainfo)
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/arnRuntimeException-java-io-FileNotFoundException-job/td-p/27063
  and etc....

Answer (score 0):

You can try to switch to yarn user instead of hue (Logout from web browser, re-login using username yarn) before submit wfs, coordinators, bundlers